# torch crossentropy loss calculation difference between 2D input and 3D input

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

i am running a test on torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss. I am using the example shown on the official page.

```
loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=False)
target = torch.randn(3, 5).softmax(dim=1)
output = loss(input, target)
```

the output is 2.05.
in the example, both the input and the target are 2D tensors. Since in most NLP case, the input should be 3D tensor and correspondingly the output should be 3D tensor as well. Therefore, i wrote the a couple lines of testing code, and found a weird issue.

```
input = torch.stack([input])
target = torch.stack([target])
output = loss(ins, ts)
```

the output is 0.9492
This result really confuse me, except the dimensions, the numbers inside the tensors are totally the same. Does anyone know the reason why the difference is?

the reason why i am testing on the method is i am working on project with Transformers.BartForConditionalGeneration. the loss result is given in the output, which is always in (1,) shape. the output is confusing.  If my batch size is greater than 1, i am supposed to get batch size number of loss instead of just one. I took a look at the code, it just simply use nn.CrossEntropyLoss(), so i am considering that the issue may be in the nn.CrossEntropyLoss() method. However, it is stucked in the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second case, you are adding an extra dimension which means that ultimately, the softmax on the logits tensor (`input`) won't be applied on a different dimension.

Here we compute the two quantities separately:

```
>>> loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
>>> input = torch.randn(3, 5, requires_grad=False)
>>> target = torch.randn(3, 5).softmax(dim=1)
```

First you have `loss(input, target)` which is identical to:

```
>>> o = -target*F.log_softmax(input, 1)
>>> o.sum(1).mean()
```

And your second scenario, `loss(input[None], target[None])`, identical to:

```
>>> o = -target[None]*F.log_softmax(input[None], 1)
>>> o.sum(1).mean()
```

Comment: does it mean that in the loss(input, target) case, the method applies log_softmax to the input on its 1st dimension, and loss(input[None], target[None]) applies log_softmax to the  1st dimension which originally the 0th dimension of the input?

Comment: This is nearly it: the softmax is always applied on `dim=1` (2nd dimension) on your prediction tensor. So this means it ends up being applied on the `dim=1-1=0` in your second scenario.